# how can i send all exception from try catch in my app android to server or email?

Tags: android, exception

I need send all exception in my app to server or email, not crash. How can i do that?

```
 try{
    }catch(Exception e){
        // here send e.getMessage() to server or email
    }
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: You can use ACRA for same https://code.google.com/p/acra/

Answer (score 0):

That's what `Exception Handling`(your try catch is there for),Your App crashes when there is some Exception.Catch it in your try block and handle it in `catch`....You can write the java code of sending an email in the catch block.The exception generated will be passed as a an argument to the catch....
I am considering that you are not talking of `NullPointerException` or the other common UI exceptions .

[**See this for learning about Sending Email**](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/email/android-sending-email-example/)

Answer (score 0):

[Crashlytisc](https://www.crashlytics.com/) is the answer to you question. Your fatal exceptions will be logged to Crashlytics server implicitly while to log non-fatal exceptions you have to do it explicitly, like following;

```
try{

} catch(Exception e){
    // Crashlytics.log(PRIORITY, TAG, MESSAGE);
    Crashlytics.log(android.util.Log.ERROR, "TAG","Message");
}
```